# Unable to launch GCP Dataflow pipeline (Spanner to GCS) using default templates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to get a default GCP Dataflow pipeline template to run (Cloud Spanner to GCS), but all my attempts to start the Pipeline/Job fail with a message indicating that a result file is missing. I've not modified any default options of the template.

```
Failed to read the result file : 
gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-11111111111/staging/template_launches/2023-06-19_10_55_21-884192550311219509/operation_result with error message: 
(8bac83beae18b544): Unable to open template file: gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-11111111111/staging/template_launches/2023-06-19_10_55_21-884192550311219509/operation_result..
```

Interestingly, I've managed to get the Pipeline working once, a few days ago. Stopped the pipeline, then attempted it again today, and all variations failed.

- I've recreated Spanner instances and DBs, and Spanner Streams
- I've re-created GCS buckets
- I've used the web interface and gcloud
- I've tried above in different regions

At this point, I am clueless why that one attempt a few days ago worked, and all of my current efforts fail

Any idea why the jobs keep failing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Let me preface: I have tried everything using the Google Cloud Console (web UI) - I wasn't able to get a pipeline running. However, creating a job with the `gcloud` CLI worked.

1. Create a service account with permissions as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#permissions_to_run_a_flex_template)
2. Create GCS bucket (and add the just created service account as principal)
3. `gcloud auth application-default login` in your local shell
4. Execute the below command. Update the `us-central1` in the template file location and everywhere else to match your region. [More params here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/flex-template/run)

```bash
gcloud dataflow flex-template run spanner-to-bigquery \
    --template-file-gcs-location=gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/2023-06-06-00_RC00/flex/Spanner_Change_Streams_to_BigQuery \
    --region us-central1 \
    --project=<your_gcs_project> \
    --service-account-email=dataflow-spanner-to-bq@<your_gcs_project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --parameters \
spannerInstanceId=development,\
spannerDatabase=main,\
spannerMetadataInstanceId=development,\
spannerMetadataDatabase=main-meta,\
spannerChangeStreamName=AllStream,\
bigQueryDataset=dev_spanner_all,\
numWorkers=1,\
enableStreamingEngine=true,\
tempLocation=gs://create_a_gs_bucket/tmp,\
stagingLocation=gs://create_a_gs_bucket/staging,\
workerRegion=us-central1
```

---

##### Previously

This isn't a solution, but merely a poor work-around. It seems that this is a GCP issue that should be addressed (or at least some type
of resolvable error should be displayed)

---

Not per se a solution, but creating a new project in GCP, and replicating a simple Spanner, GCS, and Dataflow setup worked in a new environment (GCP Project) without any issues.

It seems as if there are meta data or fragments that prevent the dataflow pipelines in my other project from launching correctly.

---

**EDIT**

Out of curiosity, I've attempted to disable all related APIs in the GCP project in which the Dataflow launch keeps failing. Even after disabling and re-enabling them, it still keeps failing on launch.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely a problem with permissions or the service account being used. Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#permissions_to_run_a_flex_template for the roles you need to assign to the service account being used.

If you are still having issues and the error is still generic, you should probably file a support case with the job ID so the team can look further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't believe that it's an IAM issue because a) it worked a day prior and I did not make *ANY* IAM changes b) it also immediately worked in a new project

Comment: any idea what's going on here? In some GCP projects I can simply create Spanner, the Dataflow pipeline and it works, in others I can try whatever I want and I don't get a conclusive error message on why it's failing. It always appears the job is not able to find the template it the GS bucket (but the template should be there automatically, as I leave all optional fields blank). When a job runs great, but getting it off the ground feels incredibly non-deterministic